# How to margin bottom for a button inside UIScrollview?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have some UIViews (labels,textviews,buttons) inside a UIScrollview. I used IB to design UI. I want to put a button margin bottom 20px to uiscollview. In android it's easy for me to margin bottom/top/left/right for a view to other. But how can i do that in iOS? I have to code for this or just adjust some info in IB?Im quite new to iOS, please help me. Thank a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using auto-layout, you would have to make the scroll view 20 points taller and manipulate the frame of the button:

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(button.frame), CGRectGetMinY(button.frame) - 20, CGRectGetWidth(button.frame), CGRectGetHeight(button.frame));
```

If you are using auto-layout, you have to add a constraint that sets the bottom spacing to the superview to 20 (or `default`).